Does this two bathroom plumbing design respect physics ? Does it meet code?
I have a symmetrical design for 2 bathrooms, where each one has a toilet, a sink, a  clothes washer and bath tub.
I have attached 3D drawing of the circuit
The vertical vent pipes shown are inside the wall separating the two bathrooms.
Toilets, sinks and washing machine are "back to back".

At the left there are 2 toilets,
they are wet vented by a branch receiving 2 sinks (3 FU total).
2 Clothes washer drain a total of 4 FU into a second wet vent, that serves 2 bathtubs.
All vent pipes are 2" (thin pipes) and the fat horizontal pipes are 3".
My primary concern is the physical soundness of the design, but I'd also like to meet the Canadian plumbing code !

wye with branch facing upwards: is that allowed?

Do you mean the rightmost wye ? Good question, perhaps both branches should connect separately at the vertical stack (not shown in drawing), each with their own wye.

or use more horizontal double wyes?  also vertical double wyes should be double sanitary tees, else the lateral sink drains need to be vented.  how long are the bathtub drains from the trap to the double wye?

Length of bathtub arms is aprox 5 feet. Do you have any pointers or info on why vertical double T are better than double Y ?

I think I found an answer (on why double T is beter than double Y for vertical) https://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?threads/double-fixture-tee-or-double-sanitary-tee.22539/page-2   (the vent gets interrupted with the double Y when surface water reaches top of horizontal segment)
